# OverflowError from complex array and imshow

Tags: python, numpy

I used to plot the output of numpy's fft2 command (comlex array) using imshow but recently it has started giving me the following error,

```
OverflowError: can't convert negative value to unsigned PY_LONG_LONG
```

it can be replicated with,

```
x = rand(10,10) + 1j
imshow(abs(x))
```

I am using python 2.7.6 and numpy 1.8.0 in the canopy environment.

Anyone else seen this or know what causes it??

Comment: it works for me with the same cofiguration but on Windows 7, 64 bit... which OS do you use?